# Need PHP Regex to scrape ZIP Code from web page

Tags: php, regex

I have data that I need to scrape on a web page that usually includes a ZIP code.  In the source code the HTML will look like this `12345<br>USA`.

My pattern looks like this:

`$pattern = '\d{5}<br>USA';`

I'm sure I'm not escaping the HTML tags or something, but I can't find the proper way to write this.

Comment: StackOverflow is not wish list nor 'write-me-code' service.

Comment: It would help if you provided some example data and the result that you want.  Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can use lookaheads and do not forget delimiters `$pattern = '/\d{5}(?=<br>USA)/';`

Comment: Looks to me like you provided everything needed to answer your question.

Comment: Missing delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pull all 5 digit zip codes:

```
(\d{5})
```

Here is a working example:

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s3bpI9/1)

Answer (score 0):

I too was thinking you needed to escape the grater/lesser thans... Think the regex lacked what you wanted to capture... Could do something like...

```
<?php    
$data = '12345<br>USA Foo Bar 12345 Blah Blah 90210';
$pattern = '#(\d{5})<br>USA#';
$matches = [];    
preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

    /*
    array (size=2)
        0 => string '12345<br>USA' (length=12)
        1 => string '12345' (length=5)
    */
```